# Setting NSTextView string with line breaks 

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

Using an action I'm setting an `NSTextView` object with a specific string. For example:

```
[textView setString:@"sentence sentence sentence"];
```

Is it possible to add line breaks to this code so that in this example I would have three lines that include the word "sentence" instead of a single "sentence sentence sentence" string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply be able to embed newline characters (`\n`) into the string as follows:

```
[textView setString:@"sentence\nsentence\nsentence"];
```

Comment: @Paul With Cocoa, it's nearly always really easy, or time to start sub-classing. ;-)

Comment: Sorry I got it ... was using forward slash! Thanks.

Comment: @Paul Got there in the end. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
[textView setString:@"sentence\nsentence\nsentence"];
```